# log4net compile error when building web deployment project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2010 running on Windows 7 64 bit.

It builds and runs fine and does not copy log4net.dll into the bin.

I now want to deploy it to a production server so I've added a web deployment project.  However as soon as I build the web deployment project I get the following error during the build phase:

*Could not load file or assembly 'log4net' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

If I look into the bin folder after the failed build, there is a log4net.dll present.

We have found this problem before on other machines when installing the 64 bit version of Crystal Reports, however this laptop does not have Crystal installed at all and the solution makes no reference to it.

I've tried making the other projects in my application x86 rather than Any CPU but the web deployment project cannot be changed from Any CPU and the error persists.

I don't knowingly use log4net, perhaps one of the DLLs we use makes a reference to it?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the 64 bit runtimes for Crystal Reports were installed on the laptop and I hadn't realised. Uninstalled and all works well.